# find out the anti-derivative of $(x^2+1)^{-1/2}$

Tags: integration

I searched for the anti-derivative of $$ (x^2+1)^{-1/2} $$ and I found that it's $\sinh^{-1}(x)$
or $\ln(x+(x^2+1)^{-1/2})$ and we didn't study yet this function 
so how can I find the anti-derivative of this function

Comment: Let $x=\sinh t$, and use the fact that $\sqrt{1+\sinh^2t}=\cosh t$ and $\sinh't=\cosh t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $x = \tan \theta$. Can you take it further..?

Comment: I'll try thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

We use the substitution $x=\tan(t)$. Now we have

$$\begin{align}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx&=\int\frac{\sec^2 t}{\sec t}\,dt
\\&=\int\sec t\,dt
\\&=\ln(\tan t+\sec t)+C
\\&=\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)+C\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You can understand it from the second definition of the function $\sinh^{-1}$.

$$\left(\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\right)'=\frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$

Simplify this expression and conclude.

---

Direct method:

We would like to get rid of the square root, and for this let a perfect square appear. How can we make $x^2$ and $x^2+1$ be both perfect squares ?

The answer lies in the remarkable identity $(a+b)^2=(a-b)^2+4ab$: adding something to a square, we get another square. We will choose $a-b=x$ and $4ab=1$, i.e. $x=a-\dfrac1{4a}$, so that $\sqrt{x^2+1}=a+\dfrac1{4a}$, and the square root is gone !

The next step is to try this substitution, noting that $dx=\left(1+\dfrac1{4a^2}\right)da$.
$$\int\frac{1+\dfrac1{4a^2}}{a+\dfrac1{4a}}da=\int\frac{da}{a}=\ln a+C=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+C'.$$
By chance, the simplification is really nice.

Comment: yeah I thought about that but the teacher will say how did you come up with multiplying by (x+(x²+1)^-1/2)). well taking x =tan teta helped me

Comment: You are right, this is a rabbit out of a hat.